Définition on a plane équation with scalar product
In one of my class I have this formula :
$\vec{r} \cdot \vec{n} = C$
With $n$ a unit vector avec $C$ a constant. This is supposed to define plane but I don't see why.

This question has nothing to do with the Mathematica computer language and must be closed.

What other ways of defining a plane (e.g. in terms of equations or functions) do you know?

This equation defines a hyperplane with dimension one less than the dimension of r. If r is in R^3, then it does indeed define a plane, which has dimension 2. We can see why by examining a simple case where the unit vector is a standard cartesian basis vector, and observing what happens when we actually compute its dot product with r:
{x, y, z} . {0, 1, 0} == y .
As you can see, we have 'picked out' just one of the components of r. Since the foregoing is constrained to equal c, we have
y == c .
This leaves the other two components unconstrained, which is precisely what a plane in R^3 is. It's not hard to verify that this works for any unit vector, by considering a rotational change of basis.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
